# JSON.parse fails

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse a JSON string. It says 'Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 361'. I have the feeling I just overlooked something silly.

```json
{
  "username": "bob",
  "user_found": "time",
  "meta": [
    {
      "name" : [
        {
          "hash" : [
            {
              "content" : "con1",
              "cont2" : "con2",
              "date" : "time"
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: I use JSON.parse btw.

Comment: JSON *is* a textual data format. You cannot *parse* a *string* to *JSON*. You are parsing a string containing JSON into a native value (e.g. a JavaScript object).

Comment: yeah i know that.. i thought everyone on this site already knew that.. thanks for clearing that up though.

Comment: @GuyRoss If you know that, then why did you title your post "parsing string to JSON"?

Comment: To people that answered this question: There is a [close reason for typos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow). Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, commas are invalid. Even for an expanding mono structure.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of the unwanted comma at the end of each of the object and array.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is saying it does not expect the bracket due to the commas saying there's going to be another item in the objects or arrays.

Remove the commas at the end of the list items:

`{
          "username": "bob",
          "user_found": "time",
          "meta": [
            {
              "name" : [
                {
                  "hash" : [
                    {
                      "content" : "con1",
                      "cont2" : "con2",
                      "date" : "time"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
    }`

Try entering it in a json validator to check that it's valid, e.g.: https://jsonlint.com/